# How do I extract a column of a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using `filter()` to return a filtered range of cells. Of that result, I only want one column of the results (so that I can sum the values of that column). What is the syntax (or function) that I can use to do that?

I want to sum the values in column D that correspond to rows with "key_match" in column C.

I want to do something like: `=SUM(GET_COLUMN(FILTER(B:F, C:C = "key_match"), D:D))`. Filter rows of columns B-F where cells in column C == "key_match"; of that result, I want to calculate the sum of the values in column D. How can I do what I would like `GET_COLUMN()` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change your filter range:

```
=sum(FILTER(D:D,C:C="key_match"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood FILTER(). I thought the range had to represent the elements used in the condition (since the docs say ["The data to be filtered."](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197), but it merely specifies what is displayed?